# Have editable label locations (dynamic) on a layer on which there is query

Tags: qgis, printing, labeling

Is it possible to have dynamic labels, set by editable x y parameters in the attribute table, on a layer which also has a query applied, in QGIS?

i.e. I want to set the query and get all the peripheral data off the map canvas, then align the remaining labels with the "move label" tools in QGIS 1.8.

If I create a second shapefile just for labelling, later on when the master dataset has edits, I end up loosing the x y coords established for the labels.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question fully. Why can't you label the features first and then apply the query?

Comment: The purpose of manually aligning the lablels is to reduce the overlap. If there is no query, the overlaps occur differently to the final product (more busy).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple answer is. No. Not with shapefiles.

Shapefiles can not have a query set (this is a OGR SQL query) and also be in edit mode.  This is a limitation coming up from OGR into QGIS not QGIS itself forcing the lack of editing.

**The answer:**

Use Spatialite, or another database format. These formats support editing while a query has been set on the layer.  So you can filter the layer using the *Query..* button and still move your label positions using the label tools.

Comment: Hi Nathan, you should make this a wiki